# XCode 14: ld: Assertion failed: (dylib != NULL), function classicOrdinalForProxy when compiling with -mcmodel=large

Tags: xcode, clang

I've just updated to Xcode 14, I compile my code with the `-mcmodel=large` flag.

This used to work on Xcode 13, but since the upgrade I get the following error:

```
0  0x104a141a0  __assert_rtn + 140
1  0x104a1d2ec  ld::tool::SymbolTableAtom<arm64>::classicOrdinalForProxy(ld::Atom const*) (.cold.2) + 0
2  0x104925598  ld::tool::LocalRelocationsAtom<arm64_32>::~LocalRelocationsAtom() + 0
3  0x104924ab8  ld::tool::SymbolTableAtom<arm64>::addImport(ld::Atom const*, ld::tool::StringPoolAtom*) + 204
4  0x104924150  ld::tool::SymbolTableAtom<arm64>::encode() + 420
5  0x104910c18  ___ZN2ld4tool10OutputFile20buildLINKEDITContentERNS_8InternalE_block_invoke_3 + 36
6  0x1ac8465f0  _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
7  0x1ac8481b4  _dispatch_client_callout + 20
8  0x1ac859b14  _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 952
9  0x1ac85a104  _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164
10  0x1aca08324  _pthread_wqthread + 228
A linker snapshot was created at:
    /tmp/project_name-2022-09-18-183942.ld-snapshot
ld: Assertion failed: (dylib != NULL), function classicOrdinalForProxy, file LinkEditClassic.hpp, line 495.
```

Removing `-mcmodel=large` solves the issue, but I need this flag for my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `-fno-objc-msgsend-selector-stubs` help?

Comment: Yes it did, thanks! can you explain what caused this issue and why did it fix it?

Comment: I played around with the linker invocation, among other things I tried `-undefined dynamic_lookup` and that made the `ld64` crash disappear. However, when I tried to execute the binary I got:

`dyld[19716]: symbol not found in flat namespace
(_objc_msgSend$UTF8String)`


This reminded me of a talk from last WWDC: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110363/ check out the section around `Message send`.

Comment: FYI I submitted https://openradar.appspot.com/FB11544896
In case you have a simpler reproducer, it would be great if you could provide info there (I can copy/paste it to the actual radar link).